# Why isn't the correct element system name translate returning when element name is used in info column?

Tags: adempiere

I have a discount element system that uses various translations of "Reducere %". In the invoice windows it shows the correct translation, but in the info invoice window it shows another translation, namely "Reducere comerciala". I have searched for "Reducere comerciala" in the language translate check and i found no match. Did anyone else encounter this problem before? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

System will show the field level Name in window. Info window will take from System Element value.
Ex:-

`Discount Column shows in Invoice Window as "Reducere %".`

Means Value in the Invoice window tab Discount column name saved as "Reducere % " in respective language translation.
Investigate :- Open the Invoice window, invoice tab and Discount field value name OR language translation window also.

`Discount Column shows in Invoice info form as "Reducere comerciala".`

Means Value in the Discount Element name saved as "Reducere comerciala " in respective language translation.
Investigate :- Open the System Element window, And select the Discount Named field OR language translation window also.